# Gmail Api access token not changing after expiration - but access still works

Tags: node.js, google-api, gmail-api

I'm developing a basic application that simply reads the emails from a specific gmail account (say fakeEmail@gmail.com) . On first run the app is granted permission to read emails of fakeEmail@gmail.com . And an **access_token**, **expiry_date** (1 hour) and **refresh_token** etc are saved to 'token.json' file.

On subsequent runs even after the access token expires, I do **NOT** see a refresh token request being made, yet the App is able to fetch and read emails from fakeEmail@gmail.com.

The app is run from command line as **'node app.js'** and it fetches the emails with a specific label and prints the content of email on console.

The method **authorize()** is the first one called every time the app is run. The **getNewToken()** is called only on first run and creates a **'token.json'** file, when the user fakeEmail@gmail.com grants permission to App to read its emails.

Here is the relevant code for this simple app:

```
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'];
const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';

const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const {google} = require('googleapis');


function authorize(credentials, callback) {
    const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;
    const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

    // Check if we have previously stored a token.
    fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
        if (err) return getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
        oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
        callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
}

function getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
    const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
        access_type: 'offline',
        scope: SCOPES,
    });

    console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
    const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout,
    });
    rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
        rl.close();
        oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
            if (err) 
                return console.error('Error retrieving access token', err);
            oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);

                // Store the token to disk for later program executions
            fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
                if (err) return console.error(err);
                console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
            });
            callback(oAuth2Client);
        });
    });
}

function startApp(){

    fs.readFile('gmailCredentials.json', (err, content) => {
        if (err) 
            return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);

        authorize(JSON.parse(content), function(auth){

            checkForMailsWithLabel(auth, strLabel, function(err, res){


                console.log("auth holds: " + util.inspect(auth) );
                    // this prints the same accessToken and expiration as the one we have in 'token.json'

                // Even though the token is expired, the app is still able to read the emails

            });

        });

    });

}
```

The code you see here is almost the exact copy of the sample they have on github: https://github.com/gsuitedevs/node-samples/blob/master/gmail/quickstart/index.js

If it matters, I have not completed the verification process with google for this App yet. Since I'm testing with my own email account, the untrusted warning at the time of granting permission is not a problem at the moment.

My question/assumption was that **googleapi** library would check to see if the access token has expired and if it has then it would request another token automatically and write it to the **'token.json'** file.

But as best as I can tell from running this code, the **'token.json'** file gets created on first run. And even if the **expiry_date** (1 hour) has expired, google library does not request another token. I say this because :

1. I don't see any update to 'token.json'
2. Even after a successfully fetch emails, The token that would have been used for fetch holds the same access token and expiration.

I could write code to check if **expiry_date** has passed and maybe force a refresh of **access_token**. But that doesn't explain why my app is able to fetch emails with the expired token.

I would rather use the recommended method and let the library handle the token if it is supposed to.

Please advice, what am I missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [Google APIs Node.js Client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client) as it is stated in [this section](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#handling-refresh-tokens):

> Access tokens expire. This library will automatically use a refresh
>   token to obtain a new access token if it is about to expire.

Therefore, you don't have to worry about getting by yourself a new access token. Although, because you are using the [Node.js Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs) and every time you run it, you set the credentials using the `.setCredentials()`, so you are explicitly declaring the access token by taking it from the json file.

For more info about the Tokens handling, you can check the [Google Auth Library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs).

Comment: Thanks @alberto. I ended up reading the documentation again and came to the same conclusion. I appreciate your response, I'll mark your answer as correct.